# How mobile messaging apps are working using socket in android oreo?

Tags: android, socket.io, android-8.0-oreo

I am developing messaging app using socket.io framework.But it is not working if i target android 26 oreo. When i read questions related to oreo everyone suggesting fcm but i wanted to know how whatsapp and other messaging apps are handling this.Is there any way to use socket.io other than below

```
if(app is in foreground&& user is online){
connect socket;
}else{
send FCM message(clicking on FCM notification will open it and connect the socket)
}
```

Comment: what is the question??

Comment: is socket.io works in background android oreo

Comment: definitely yes!!

Comment: using socket.io library i am trying to connect in android oreo but it is not working

Comment: what exception you are getting inside logcat?